# Neo4j - Get the relationship that have the latest timestamp

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When there is multiple relationships with different timestamps, I want to filter and get the latest timestamp. How do I do that?

```
(n:Node)-[r:REL{'timestamp': 12345678}]->(m:Node)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are a couple of options depending what you exactly need

```
//the highest timestamp overall
MATCH (n:Node)-[r:REL]->(m:Node)
RETURN MAX(r.timestamp)

//the highest timestamp per nodepair
MATCH (n:Node)-[r:REL]->(m:Node)
RETURN id(n),id(r),MAX(r.timestamp)

//the relationship with highest timestamp per nodepair
MATCH (n:Node)-[r:REL]->(m:Node)
WITH n,m,r,r.timestamp AS rel ORDER BY r.timestamp  DESC
RETURN n,m,collect(r)[0] AS rWithHighestTimestamp
```